# sort any type of list according to a specified function in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, typed-racket

I am trying to create a function that sorts a given list according to the specified function I have the following code so far:

```
(: partition1 (All (A) ((A A -> Boolean) (Listof A) -> (Pr (Listof A) (Listof A)))))
(define (partition1 f x)
  (match x
    ('() (Pr '() '()))
    ((cons hd '()) (Pr (list hd) '()))
    ((cons hd tl)
     (match
         (partition1 f tl)
       ((Pr A B)
        (if (f hd (first tl))
            (Pr (cons hd A) B)
            (Pr A (cons hd B))))))))

(: quicksort1 (All (A) ((A A -> Boolean) (Listof A) -> (Listof A))))
;; sort the items according to the given order and with the quicksort algorithm
(define (quicksort1 f x)
  (match x
    ('() '())
    ((cons hd tl)
     (match (partition1 f tl)
       ((Pr A B)
        (append
         (quicksort1 A)
         (list hd)
         (quicksort1 B)))))))
```

My goal is to create a goal that does something like this:

```
> (quicksort string<? (list "a" "g" "h" "q" "w" "z" "x" "m" "n" "p"))
==> (list "a" "g" "h" "m" "n" "p" "q" "w" "x" "z")
```

BUT, the above function keeps giving me the following error:

```
match: no matching clause for '("p")
```

I have tried to do everything I could to eliminate this error, but in vain. I am learning programming on my own at home and would love any and all assistance! Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: lol yea true that just edited to reflect a question!

Comment: Recursing to `quicksort1` instead of calling `quicksort2` should take care of that error.

Comment: no that didn't do it unfortunately.

Comment: It does for me if I replace your `Pr` type with regular pairs. It doesn't sort correctly, though. (Please include your type definitions in your questions, btw.)

Comment: so how do you make the sort correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your partitioning function.

It should take a function of just one argument, and you use the function to classify the list elements into those for which it's true and those for which it's false.

Here's a working version in untyped Racket.
It should be easy to modify.

First, partitioning.
Note that a singleton list is not a special case.

```
(define (partition left? ls)
  (match ls
    ('() (cons '() '()))
    ((cons hd tl)
     (match
         (partition left? tl)
       ((cons l r)
        (if (left? hd)
            (cons (cons hd l) r)
            (cons l (cons hd r))))))))
```

And if we use the list's head as the pivot element, sorting could look like this:

```
(define (quicksort compare ls)
  (match ls
    ('() '())
    ((cons hd tl)
     (match (partition (lambda (x) (compare x hd)) tl)
       ((cons l r)
        (append
         (quicksort compare l)
         (list hd)
         (quicksort compare r)))))))


> (quicksort < '(3 4 5 2 1 7 6))
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
> (quicksort string<? '("a" "g" "h" "q" "w" "z" "x" "m" "n" "p"))
'("a" "g" "h" "m" "n" "p" "q" "w" "x" "z")
> (quicksort string>? '("a" "g" "h" "q" "w" "z" "x" "m" "n" "p"))
'("z" "x" "w" "q" "p" "n" "m" "h" "g" "a")
```

Comment: but when i use your code i get the following error: match: no matching clause for (Pr '() '("g" "h" "q" "w" "z" "x" "m" "n"))

Comment: It's impossible to guess what's wrong without seeing your code, particularly as the code in your question doesn't exhibit the error in your question. It doesn't even typecheck, so you must be running something else.

Comment: I am using DrRacket with typed/racket. What are you using? I am really confused.

Comment: If I paste your code into DrRacket (version 6.7), there are two type errors. (I also added a suitable `Pr` struct.) You'll get better help if you copy and paste the code you're running.